# Ejabberd Server not allowing user to login

Tags: ejabberd, pidgin

Steps to Create the Issue:

1. logged into my ejabberd admin portal.
2. Added a User.
3. Attempted to login with the same configuration as a working account.
4. Pidgeon says "Not Authorized"

Additional info:
I see the user in the list of "Users" in the admin portal.

Whats wrong?

Note: 
Restarting the server/service is not a viable option at the moment.
I don't know much about this at the moment, I inherited this project from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I entered the password wrong when I created the account. It works fine